# How to prevent Play Store counting installs - uninstalls of an app during development/testing the app locally?

Tags: android, appium-android, android-vitals

We run automation smoke tests on production apk on periodic basis via Appium Tool. But we observed that this impact the Users Statistics provided as "Android-Vitals" on Play Store such as "User Lost". This is because, developers keep installing/uninstalling the app and this happens in appium automation too.

I generally don't prefer to make separate apk for testing, unless if no other solution exists.

So I want to know the possible ways to prevent Play Store statistics data from getting skewed due to development activities.

Answer (score 0):

You could try disabling data sharing to google per ["View app statistics"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628)

Quote from the link : "Some metrics are calculated based on data from users who have agreed to share their data with developers in aggregate."

To do that :

1. Open your device's Settings app.
2. Tap Google And then More (three vertical dots) And then Usage & diagnostics.
3. Turn Usage & diagnostics off.

Per : ["Share usage & diagnostics information with Google"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6078260)